# Load different JS for Mobile and Desktop

Tags: javascript, java, php, adsense

I am trying to use a JS for loading the Ad code when the user scrolls.
the code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ var la=!1;window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){(0!=document.documentElement.scrollTop&&!1===la||0!=document.body.scrollTop&&!1===la)&&(!function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(e,a)}(),la=!0)},!0);//]]></script>
```

Now, I want that, the above JS should load only for mobile,
and for desktop it should load:

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

I will be obeliged to you for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional in your javascript to check the window size and then set the script tag using javascript, set relavent attributes and content according to the condintional, then append your head.

```js
let mediaBreakpointSize = 600; /* Change this size and test outcome */

let scriptTag = '';

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < mediaBreakpointSize) {

  scriptTag = document.createElement("script");

  let content = '//<![CDATA[ var la=!1;window.addEventListener("scroll",function(){(0!=document.documentElement.scrollTop&&!1===la||0!=document.body.scrollTop&&!1===la)&&(!function(){var e=document.createElement("script");e.type="text/javascript",e.async=!0,e.src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];a.parentNode.insertBefore(e,a)}(),la=!0)},!0);//]]';
  
  scriptTag.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  
  scriptTag.defer = true;
  
  scriptTag.textContent = content;
  
  document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
  
} else {

  scriptTag = document.createElement("script");

  scriptTag.async = true;

  scriptTag.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";

  document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
}

console.log(scriptTag)
```

Comment: Why is that <head> tag at the end of your answer?

Comment: Left it in there by accident.

Comment: Not working... For desktop it is working normally. But for mobile it is not

Comment: When i decrease the BreakPoint to 100 it even works for mobile but not onscroll

Comment: Hmm works in responsive display mode on Mozilla and Chrome both set as mobile. When you say it does not work, are you talking about the script tag itself changing to the proper script for the media in the conditional?